# WPF equivalent to Flex states

Tags: c#, apache-flex, states, equivalence, cross-language

Flex has a very elegant concept of states which let you define what components should be displayed and what should they look like based on the parent component "state".
For example, you could define some Login window states as "Normal","ChangePassword","Sending" or "Failed" and adjust the layout accordingly.
**What is the equivalent concept in WPF?**

Answer (score 2):

WPF has visual states concept. See [VisualState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate.aspx) and [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx) classes.